# NTE912 Pinout Confusion

Tags: datasheet, bjt

The NTE912 contains three standalone BJT transistors and two configured as a differential pair. The datasheet can be found at

http://www.nteinc.com/specs/900to999/pdf/nte912.pdf

and gives a pin configuration that looks like

[image]

Short of hooking the chip up and using trial-and-error to see what is the base/emitter/collector, does anyone know how to decipher this pinout?

Comment: I'll bet this 912 part has the same transistor arrangement as as a CA-3046. [Image here](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn34/fn341.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to what I read it is a pin to pin equivalent with [CA3086](http://www.intersil.com/data/fn/fn483.pdf)

Comment: Ah maybe NTE couldn't use the same pin diagram as Intersil? I notice they pulled some of the introduction wording right from the Intersil datasheet.